# JQM: added collapsible in collapsibleset is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, undefined, jquery-mobile-collapsible

```
    if (toadd.length > 0) { //added new admin
        jQuery.each(toadd, function(entry) {

            jQuery("#add_fund_form_setup_admins" ).append(''+

                '<div user_id="'+toadd[entry]+'" id="#add_fund_form_setup_admin_'+toadd[entry]+'" data-role="collapsible">'+
                    '<h3>'+jQuery("#add_fund_form_select_admins option[value="+toadd[entry]+" ]").text()+'</h3>'+
                    '<p>'+
                    '<label for="add_fund_form_admin_zp_size_percent_'+toadd[entry]+'">Some Label:</label>'+
                    '<input type="range" name="add_fund_form_admin_zp_size_percent_'+toadd[entry]+'" id="add_fund_form_admin_zp_size_percent_'+toadd[entry]+'" value="50" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true">'+ 
                        '<br />'+

                    '<label for="add_fund_form_admin_zp_size_fixed_'+toadd[entry]+'">Some more label:</label>'+
                    '<input type="number" name="add_fund_form_admin_zp_size_fixed_'+toadd[entry]+'" pattern="[0-9]*" id="add_fund_form_admin_zp_size_fixed_'+toadd[entry]+'" value="">'+
                        '<br />'+

                    '<label for="add_fund_form_admin_zp_fixed_payout_period_'+toadd[entry]+'" class="select">Period:</label>'+
                    '<select name="add_fund_form_admin_zp_fixed_payout_period_'+toadd[entry]+'" id="add_fund_form_admin_zp_fixed_payout_period_'+toadd[entry]+'" data-native-menu="false">'+
                        '<option>Select period</option>'+
                            '<option value="weekly">weekly</option>'+
                            '<option value="monthly">monthly</option>'+
                            '<option value="quaterly">quarterly</option>'+
                            '<option value="yearly">yearly</option>'+
                    '</select>'+
                        '<br />'+

                '</p>'+
                '</div>').collapsibleset( "refresh" );

        });
        jQuery("#add_fund_form_setup_admins_lbl").show();
        jQuery('[data-role="content"]').trigger('create');
        jQuery( "#add_fund_form_setup_admins" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );  
                    jQuery('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
        jQuery('[data-role=collapsible-set]').collapsibleset().trigger('create');

                    **alert(jQuery("#add_fund_form_setup_admin_" + toadd[entry] ).attr("user_id"));**  
    }
```

the content is added to the page and is present there. IDs are OK. All visual is made.

In the last alert i get "undefined", why? 
when i try to access added element i cot nothing happening without any errors...why?
many thanks for help.

Comment: In the alert case your _entry_ variable is outside the scope of the $each; what are you trying to do?

Comment: i have tryed alerting by the real id.   '<div user_id="'+toadd[entry]+'" id="**#add**_fund_form_setup_admin_'+toadd[entry]+'"

the problem was in # char in ID.
i would rather go to sleep...